# Validating fields always giving invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, form-for

I'm kind of new to ruby on rails. I have a User model with the field email, group and city. I'm giving two registration forms, one for mentor and  one for mentee. When I add validation to any field , it's always returning invalid.

I'm using form_for for displaying form. Is this invalid error because I'm displaying two forms? And I'm not using attr_accessible in my model . I'm using strong parameters in my controller.

My form for Mentor and mentee looks like this

```
%h1 Mentor Registration
%h2 Partcipating PE/DE/Dir/Sr Dir/VP Information
.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    = form_for(@user) do |f|
     = f.label :'Cisco Email'
     = f.email_field :cisco_email
     = f.label :'Current group'
     = f.text_field :current_group
     = f.label :'Current work location,city'
     = f.text_field :work_city


%h2 Strengths: check at least one box that apply, can select at most 3
.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    = form_for(@user) do |f|
     = f.check_box :conflict_resolution
     = f.label :conflict_resolution, 'Conflict Resolution'
     = f.check_box :customer_know_how
     = f.label :customer_know_how, 'Customer Know How'
     = f.check_box :exec_acheive_results
     = f.label :exec_acheive_results, 'Executive to achieve results'
     = f.check_box :personal_branding
     = f.label :personal_branding, 'Personal Branding'
     = f.check_box :leading_change 
     = f.label :leading_change, 'Leading Change'
     = f.check_box :align_and_influence    
     = f.label :align_and_influence, 'Align and Influence'
     = f.check_box :managing_without_authority
     = f.label :managing_without_authority, 'Managing Without Authority'
     = f.check_box :win_win_negotiation
     = f.label :win_win_negotiation, 'Win-Win Negotiation'
     = f.check_box :career_exploration
     = f.label :career_exploration, 'Career Exploration'
     = f.check_box :effective_communication
     = f.label :effective_communication, 'Effective Communication'
     = f.check_box :think_out_box
     = f.label :think_out_box, 'Creative Thinking/Think Out Of the box'
     = f.check_box :tech_know
     = f.label :tech_know, 'Technical Know-How, List Areas'
     = f.text_field :tech_areas
     = f.check_box :other
     = f.label :other, 'Any Other'      
     = f.text_field :other_areas
     = f.submit "Register Me", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

in the user controller I have this

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


    def index
    end


    def show
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
     @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
        if @user.save
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to the CSG Mentoring Tool!"
            redirect_to @user
        else
        flash[:notice] = "Error regsitering."
            render :new
             end
    end

    private
    ##Strong Parametres
    def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:user_role, :cisco_email, :current_group,     :work_city, :conflict_resolution, :customer_know_how, :personal_branding,
        :leading_change, :exec_acheive_results, :align_and_influence, :managing_without_authority, :career_exploration, :win_win_negotiation, :effective_communication, :think_out_box, :tech_know, :other, :tech_areas, :other_areas)          
    end
end
```

and I'm adding validation in the user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :work_city, :presence => true  

end
```

Now, even though i enter something into work location and submit, it's giving 'Error registration'.

Comment: `My car is broken. how to fix it?` - we cannot help you in any way without seeing your code.

Comment: I suspect you're receiving a more descriptive error message than that. Look in your console or development.log and see what's really going on.

Comment: Error registration is what I'm displaying in flash when the user fails to register. When I'm adding validation to any one of the fields, it's always giving error and not letting the user register.

Comment: Check params in create action. And in else block use `puts @user.errors.full_messages` to known which validations are failing. You would probably get the answer

Answer (score 0):

With HAML, your fields should be nested under the form_for...

```
.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    = form_for(@user) do |f|
      = f.label :'Cisco Email'
      = f.email_field :cisco_email
      ...
```

As it is no fields are being returned so that's why your validation is not passing.

maxcal also makes the good point that you can't distinguish the two forms... best to have all fields under the single form.

Comment: @maxcal and @ Steve : I nested all the fields into one form. It is still giving  the same flash message.

Comment: And did you indent the fields?  In my illustration I was showing that the `f.label` and `f.email_field` etc. need to be indented compared to the `form_for` (which is what I mean by nested)

Comment: My apologies ! I'm a newbie to Stackoverflow. Didn't know how to post the code. When I was indenting it for 4 spaces, I missed out the indentation of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the errors is due to the fact that you have two different forms. Thats how HTML forms work.

```
<form action="/foo" id="A" method="post">
  <input name="user[email]" type="email" value="test@example.com" />
</form>

<form  action="/foo" id="B" method="post">
  <input name="user[user_name]" type="string" value="John Doe" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit button only the values in form B will be sent.

You need to nest all your inputs under `= form_for(@user)`.

### Added.

On a side note. Creating a separate database column on `users` for every possible strength is not a very viable approach. Instead what is commonly used is called associations. We would say that a `User` has many `Strengths` and `Strength` has many users.

We call this relationship `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :strengths
  # ... more code
end

class Strength
  # description: string
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Some examples of how associations can be used:

```
Strength.all # all the strengths
User.last.strengths
douchebags = User.joins(:strengths)
                 .where(strengths: { description: 'Personal Branding' })
```

[image: The database layout]

This is really big topic and I'm not going to go farther into it here. There are tons of guide, tutorials and screencasts on how associations work. The official guides are good starting point:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I nested all the fields into one form. It is still giving the same flash error message

Comment: A friendly word of advise; just saying it gives me an error does not actually get you anywhere in programming. You need to first of all develop some problem solving abilities of your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs.I appreciate it.  I was using strong parameters in my controller but now i removed it and added attr_accessible in my model.  Validations are working now. I don't know whether it is the correct approach or not , but it's working. And about the databse , I have a set of predefined strengths that I was asked to display on both the forms . So I just had to design my forms like that. Thanks a lot :D